# AdMob load ad failure

Tags: android, admob

Ok the problem is solved without doing anything.

I used the following guide: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start. and it didn't work so instead,, I used .addTestDevice in onCreate(). However, ads (requesting banner) still fail to load

```
 AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addTestDevice("The Correct Code extracted from logcat")
            .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The error is the following:

```
        06-22 19:40:49.327    2341-2360/nocompany.CashingCash D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads117496078.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
06-22 19:40:49.377    2341-2341/nocompany.CashingCash I/Ads﹕ CsiReporterFactory: CSI is not enabled. No CSI reporter created.
06-22 19:40:49.377    2341-2341/nocompany.CashingCash I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
06-22 19:40:49.397    2341-2360/nocompany.CashingCash D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: --- END 'ads117496078.jar' (success) ---
06-22 19:40:49.397    2341-2360/nocompany.CashingCash D/dalvikvm﹕ DEX prep '/data/data/nocompany.CashingCash/cache/ads117496078.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 71ms
06-22 19:40:52.157    2341-2376/nocompany.CashingCash W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
06-22 19:40:52.177    2341-2341/nocompany.CashingCash I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMixedContentMode, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.ads.internal.t.h.<init>
06-22 19:40:52.217    2341-2341/nocompany.CashingCash I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
06-22 19:40:52.217    2341-2341/nocompany.CashingCash W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 2
06-22 19:41:52.227    2341-2341/nocompany.CashingCash I/Ads﹕ Starting ad request.
06-22 19:41:52.549    2341-3515/nocompany.CashingCash W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
06-22 19:41:52.569    2341-2341/nocompany.CashingCash I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
06-22 19:41:52.569    2341-2341/nocompany.CashingCash W/Ads﹕ Failed to load ad: 2
```

Is this possibly due to my canvas covering the whole screen?

Canvas code:

```
 android:id="@+id/rec_canvas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000" />
```

OK. I think I confirmed that the problem is the canvas. Can I give the ad priority over the canvas by inflation or something? Canvas refreshes every second btw. Or can I reframe my canvas to cover all parts of the screen but the ad?

Some other relevant code:
(activity main)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity"
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/xadView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

(strings)

```
    <string name="banner_ad_unit_id">ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111</string>
```

(manifest)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/
```

Visibility error

```
    06-22 19:48:56.968    2341-2341/? I/Ads﹕ Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
06-22 19:48:56.968    2341-2341/? I/Ads﹕ Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
06-22 19:49:01.648    1575-1575/? D/HeadsetTangibleController﹕ [TangibleIO] HeadsetTangibleController onAction action = android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED
06-22 19:49:32.518  11424-15647/? E/Ads﹕ Failed to connect to https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/drt/m. No DRT retrieved.
```

To confirm network connection for phone, accessed websites and works.
I tested on emulator and it works but it doesn't work for actual phone (Lg G3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to care about tag `Ads`:

```
06-22 19:18:17.207  20075-20110/nocompany.CashingCash W/Ads﹕ There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
```

Because of sometimes Google Admob does not work well then it is not successful in loading the advertisement. Make sure that you have a good internet connection and correct following guide.

Comment: I do have a good internet connection (4G). I looked over logcat again and it mentioned that the Ad was covered. I'll copy the code in a minute

Comment: please attach you logical with tag filter as Ads

Answer (score 3):

**care about tag Ads:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  tools:context=".MainActivity"
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/xadView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

put the second line witch i put in this example

**xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"**

at the same place where you can see in my answer

this will solve your problem